# Linking tables in MYSQL - Do I need a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this schema, it's one of my first:

```
CREATE TABLE location (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
locality VARCHAR(20),
administrative_area_level_1 VARCHAR(20),
administrative_area_level_2 VARCHAR(20),
administrative_area_level_3 VARCHAR(20),
loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
rad VARCHAR (17),
updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)

CREATE TABLE country {
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
iso VARCHAR(20),
loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
rad VARCHAR (17),
updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
}
```

First of all could you tell me how I can link my location table to a country table so that it is also required (i.e you can't have a location without a country).

Further to this, could anyone tell me why SQL fiddle might be giving me this error on my schema:

> Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE country' at line 12:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE location (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   locality VARCHAR(20),
   administrative_area_level_1 VARCHAR(20),
   administrative_area_level_2 VARCHAR(20),
   administrative_area_level_3 VARCHAR(20),
   loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
   rad VARCHAR (17),
   updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   );



  CREATE TABLE country (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    iso VARCHAR(20),
    loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
    rad VARCHAR (17),
    updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  );
```

Remove the curly braces and add semicolon(;) after the statement

Comment: When I use this with SQLfiddle it still gives me an error Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE country (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
iso ' at line 12:

Comment: edited the code missing semicolon at the end of the CREATE statement

Answer (score 1):

Your second table creation is failed since you're using wrong brackets (`{..}` instead of `(..)`)

As for foreign key - all explanation could be found in manual pages ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)).

Comment: Oh, now I get the error Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE country (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
iso ' at line 12:

Comment: I have successfully executed your creation syntax (using `(..)` brackets, of cause)

Comment: Yes, sometimes it does. This is not the first time and since some time me, for example, not use SQLfiddle (only local sandbox MySQL instance instead)

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL fiddle issue can be solve with following query 

CREATE TABLE country (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(20),
iso VARCHAR(20),
loc VARCHAR (17) NOT NULL,
rad VARCHAR (17),
updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: Whe I use this with SQL fiddle it gives me this error: Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE country (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
iso ' at line 12:

Answer (score 0):

you should use '(' instead of '{' while creating the tables.
now, how to join the two tables.
there is no need of a foreign key to join the two tables at all.
there is a field 'id' which is same in both of the tables and you can use this field to join the two tables.
by using the following query:

```
SELECT l.administrative_area_level_1,c.name 
FROM country c,location l
WHERE l.id=c.id
```

the above query will show you the administrative_area_level_1 and name fields from location and country table respectively where the value of the id column will be same.
but you should note that the id column in the location should represent the same record as that id field in the country.
otherwise it will show you the wrong data.
basically foreign key is needed to ensure that there will be no ambiguity in the table
for example if there is an id column and corresponding to that id there is another column in other table.
and if there exists an id in the second table and not in the first table there can be ambiguity there.
so if we put id under the foreign key referencing the second table then if there is an id update in the first table then it would also be updated in the second table.so you can't create your own id in the second column.
 hope this help you in the foreign key concept.